# Using jQuery Form Plugin with Rails, works on first comment post but not after

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using JQuery Form Plugin as follows:

```
$('document').ready( ->
  options = 
    beforeSubmit: markComment
  $('.comment_form').ajaxForm(options)
)

markComment = (arr, $form, options) ->
  $form.closest('.comment_area').addClass('add_comment_here')
```

When the comment gets created the following javascript gets called server side:

```
$('.add_comment_here').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial =>'activities/comments', :locals => {:activity => @activity})) %>")
$('.add_comment_here').removeClass('add_comment_here')
$('.add_comments_box').fadeOut()
```

A comment post works fine the first time, but on the second attempt I get 'Template is missing' as if the form was being submitted before the AJAX method got to be called.  How do I get it work the same for multiple comments?

This is the form_tag in haml:

```
=form_tag({ :action => 'create', :controller => 'comments' }, { :class => 'comment_form'}) do
```

Comment: Are you adding a `.comment_form` after `$(document).ready()` would be triggered?

Comment: No, I don't think so but I also don't think I follow.  I'm really new to javascript.

Comment: @mu_is_too_short, I think understand now, and I think that's it. . I render the html containing the .comment_form when it's submitted the first time. . how do I get around this or rectify it?

Comment: @mu_is_too_short, I'm going to change the code so it doesn't re-render the form

Comment: The last option sounds like the best approach but have a look at Ryan's explanation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the comments above, I'm not sure this answer is needed.  If you still want to re-render your form, then you just need to make sure to re-ajax the new element once it's been added to the page.  Just add that `$('.comment_form').ajaxForm(options)` into the JS that gets run after the re-render.

What I believe is happening is that your response ends up removing the previous form from the document and then adds a new one.  When this happens, any JS that might have been "attached" to that previous form element is removed along with the element.  If your response creates a brand new form element, you have to make sure to apply any special JS additions to the brand new element.

Also be sure to re-define the `options` in your response JS, since the previous `options` declaration will have fallen out of scope.  You may just be able to put the options+ajaxing into a separate function called something like `function ajaxify_forms` and just call that function on document ready and then also whenever you replace the form element.